# Multiple tag search

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make multiple tag search in my post tags.
So I have a table `tags_posts` (columns are `id_tag` and `id_post`).

If user types a few tag to input (I'll seperate and parse them using comma and array), sql query should return all posts that has all tags in user's input.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_post, content, author_id, created, updated, username 
FROM tags_posts 
INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id=tags_posts.id_post 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id=posts.author_id 
WHERE id_tag IN (1,2,3)
```

But in this case if any one of tag ids has in any post, that posts returns. But I'm looking for all tags for that post.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Since you are new, I recommend reading this before posting: whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM posts a JOIN
(
 SELECT p.id
   FROM tag_posts tp JOIN posts p 
     ON tp.post_id = p.id JOIN tags t 
     ON tp.tag_id = t.id
  WHERE t.name IN ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
  GROUP BY p.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) = 3 -- << should the number of tags used in WHERE clause
) q ON a.id = q.id
```

The `HAVING` clause ensures that the query returns only posts that have **all** (three in example) tags.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e851/2)** demo

Comment: It looks like what I'm looking for but what is a and q on last statement: `ON a.id = q.id`

Comment: @alayli These are aliases in outer select for `posts` table and the subquery respectively.

Comment: After checking sqlfiddle demo, i tried and and it works now. Thanks @peterm.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.id, posts.content, posts.created, posts.updated, posts.author_id, users.username 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN users
    on users.id = posts.author_id 
INNER JOIN tags_posts 
    ON tags_posts.id_post = posts.id
INNER JOIN tags 
    ON tags.id = tags_posts.id_tag 
WHERE tags.name = 'tag1' 
    AND tags.name = 'tag2' 
    AND tags.name = 'tag3'
```

Comment: Thanks but not works as I expected. tag1, tag2, tag3 (all of them) should have in returning post. But in this case, if any of that tags in that post, post returns.

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should retrieve all posts with ALL keywords specified in it :)

Comment: I'm looking to what's missing but after tag1 anything I wrote with `and` returns empty result from sql.

Answer (score -1):

Pass tag ids to be searched separated by comma in a string say $search and use the following query:

```
select id_post from tags_posts where id_tag  IN ($search)
```

Comment: Not what I except. If you look [at the your demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e851/27), result collects all tags in that array. Result should only `post2` because only `post2` has `ALL tags`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the "IN" statement in MySQL for your parsed tags?

```
SELECT *
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Tag_Posts 
    ON Tag_Posts.Id_post = Posts.id
INNER JOIN Tags
    ON Tags.id = Tag_Posts.Id_tag
WHERE Tags.name IN('PHP','SQL','LAMP')
```

Comment: Not what I except. If you look [at the your demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e851/23), result collects all tags in that array. Result should only post2 because only post2 has ALL tags.